# В чем разница между item и arr[index]

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, в чем разница между item и arr[index] на примере такой задачи

Напишите функцию `colonOdd(num)`, которая принимает число num в качестве аргумента и вставляет двоеточие (:) между двумя нечетными числами. Например, если вводится число 55639217, то на выходе должно быть 5:563:921:7.

```
 function colonOdd(num){
          return num.split('')
        .map((item,index,arr) => arr[index] % 2 != 0 && arr[index + 1] % 2 != 0 ? item + ':': item).join('')
        }
        console.log(colonOdd('556'));
        //output: 5:56
```

Вот так работает
А вот так - нет

```
 function colonOdd(num){
      return num.split('').map((item,index,arr) => item % 2 != 0 && item[index + 1] % 2 != 0 ? item + ':': item).join('')
    }
    console.log(colonOdd('556')); 
   //output: 5:5:6
```

Comment: а не надо ли item перевести в число предварительно?

Comment: Разница между `item` и `arr[index]` — ни в чём, а вот между `arr[index + 1]` и `item[index + 1]` разница огромнейшая

Comment: Точно!!!!!!!!!!!! Спасибо!

Comment: Тест с числом которое заканчивается на нечетную цифру, работает некорректно
например:
Тест 557, выдаст 5:57:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

item[index + 1]  зачем это? это от значения находится какой-то индекс. Первый вариант более правильный, т.к. работает с массивом по индексам, а следующий элемент в итерации взять... проблематично

Comment: Спасибо! В упор проблему не видел, теперь дошло!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function colonOdd(num) {
    return num.split('')
  .map((item,index,arr) => (arr[index] % 2 != 0 && arr[index + 1] % 2 != 0 && index < arr.length-1) ? item + ':': item).join('')
  }

console.log(colonOdd('55617'));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]